Is ᅟퟁ attested?
I happened to be curious why ᅟퟁ (old hangul Jamo for ㅣㅗㅣ) is written with the small ㅣ underneath instead of on the right, so I went to look at the Unicode proposal from 2006, skimmed through the References, but couldn't find it. I expected to be able to find it after the document marked UX222 (because it should be UX223), but it's just not there?
I was, however, able to find ᅟힱ in the word ᄆힱ쟈란, which also features the ㅣ underneath. I don't know what languages this document is supposed to be in but that's a different question. But I suspect that if ᅟퟁ does exist, it would also be in the same document, 동문유해.
